# How do I update GUI after each iteration?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, dispatcher

I have a label and canvas representing a coordinate system. In the canvas there is a node, which should change it's place every time a calculation is made. This is done until a specific stopping criteria is meet.

I also have a label containing coordinate info for the note. I want to be able to see the node and label update on every iteration(every time the calculation is made).

I have looked a the dispatcher, but my GUI will only update when the calculations are done. Below is what I have tried doing with the Dispatcher for the label.

```
While(notDone = true){
//Calculations made here

Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                    DispatcherPriority.Background,
                    new Action(() => this.aLabel.Text = aString ));
}
```

I have been looking at solutions for similar problems and some solutions involve threads. Do I have to use threads to update my GUI?

Comment: do the calculation in a separate thread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create delegate and event for handling information changes

```
public delegate void SomeInfoChangeDelegate(object o);
public event SomeInfoChangeDelegate InfoChangeEvent = null;
```

Assign listener to event and start thread w/ calculations

```
InfoChangeEvent += new SomeInfoChangeDelegate(OnInfoChanged);
Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SomeWorkerThread));
t.Start();
```

Make calculation thread and event listener

```
    void OnInfoChanged(object o)
    {
        // Update label
    }

    protected void SomeWorkerThread(object o)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            if( i % 10 == 0 )
            {
                if(InfoChangeEvent != null)
                {
                    InfoChangeEvent(i);
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

And don't forget to stop thread :)

Comment: Thanks for all answers! I ended up using Mr A. idea, which works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

.Net has a class exactly for you, my friend!

[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Do all the heavy lifting (your loop) in the DoWork method and update your GUI in ReportProgress.
See the documentation for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're performing calculations in UI (main) thread, it can't process messages until they're done. Move calculations to another thread and notify main thread in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you use WPF/Silverlight make class with INotifyPropertyChanged implemented and bind element positions to properties. On RaisePropertyChanged("PropName") position 'll be changed.

Comment: No but it won't render dynamically.  All processing on them main thread (UI) is complete before rendering.